# BehaviorSubject keeps reseting inside lazy loaded module

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular6, facade

I'm trying to implement a `facade.service` for a lazy loaded module.

#### Stackblitz [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/behavior-error-so?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcore%2Fservices%2Fta-facade.service.ts)

---

facade

```
@Injectable()
export class TaFacadeService {
  private _state: TAState;
  private _store: BehaviorSubject<TAState>;
  private _state$: Observable<TAState>;

  ano$: Observable<number>;
  loading$: Observable<boolean>;
  mes$: Observable<number>;
  tarjetas$: Observable<DatoListaAmarilla[]>;
  url$: Observable<string>;
  rutaSubscription: Subscription;
  codUser: string;
  urlEp: any;

  /**
   * Viewmodel que computa el estado completo una vez que esta listo
   * o es actualizado
   */
  vm$: Observable<TAState> = combineLatest(
    this.ano$,
    this.loading$,
    this.mes$,
    this.tarjetas$,
    this.url$
  ).pipe(
    map(([ano, loading, mes, tarjetas, url]) => {
      return { ano, loading, mes, tarjetas, url };
    })
  );

  /**
   * Vigilar 2 streams para desencadenar la busqueda de las tarjetas
   * y el update del state
   */
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private authService: AuthService) {
    console.log(`// ----------------------- //`);
    console.log(`Facade Service Instanciated`);
    console.log(`// ----------------------- //`);
    this._state = {
      ano: new Date().getFullYear(),
      loading: false,
      mes: new Date().getMonth() + 1,
      tarjetas: [],
      url: ""
    };

    this.urlEp = {
      emitidas: "Emitida",
      recibidas: "Recibida",
      prevencion: "Prevencion",
      zonal: "JefeZonal",
      comite: "Comite",
      detalle: "Detalle",
      persona: "Todos",
      ejecutor: "Ejecutor",
      ver: "Todos"
    };

    this._store = new BehaviorSubject<TAState>(this._state);
    this._state$ = this._store.asObservable();

    this.ano$ = this._state$.pipe(
      map(state => state.ano),
      tap(state => console.log(`Ano es: ${state}`)),
      distinctUntilChanged()
    );
    this.loading$ = this._state$.pipe(
      map(state => state.loading),
      tap(state => console.log(`Loading es: ${state}`)),
      distinctUntilChanged()
    );
    this.mes$ = this._state$.pipe(
      map(state => state.mes),
      tap(state => console.log(`Mes es: ${state}`)),
      distinctUntilChanged()
    );
    this.tarjetas$ = this._state$.pipe(
      map(state => state.tarjetas),
      tap(state => console.log(`tarjetas es:`, state)),
      distinctUntilChanged()
    );
    this.url$ = this._state$.pipe(
      map(state => state.url),
      tap(state => console.log(`url$ es: ${state}`)),
      distinctUntilChanged()
    );

    this.codUser = this.authService.user;
    combineLatest(this.ano$, this.mes$, this.url$)
      .pipe(
        switchMap(([ano, mes, url]) => {
          if (!url) {
            console.log(`url es desde switchmap: ${url}`);
            return of(null);
          }
          return this.getTarjetasAmarillas(url, ano, mes);
        })
      )
      .subscribe(tarjetas => {
        console.log(`tarjetas del subscribe es:`, tarjetas);
        this.updateState({ ...this._state, tarjetas, loading: false });
      });
  }

  getStateSnapshop(): TAState {
    return { ...this._state };
  }

  buildSerchControls(): FormGroup {
    const form = new FormGroup({
      ano: new FormControl("", Validators.required),
      mes: new FormControl("", Validators.required)
    });

    form
      .get("ano")
      .valueChanges.pipe(
        debounceTime(300),
        distinctUntilChanged()
      )
      .subscribe(ano => this.updateAno(ano));
    form
      .get("mes")
      .valueChanges.pipe(
        debounceTime(300),
        distinctUntilChanged()
      )
      .subscribe(mes => this.updateMes(mes));
    return form;
  }

  buildUrl(userCod: string, tipo: string, ano: number, mes?: number) {
    const URL = "SOMEURL";
    const tipoTA = tipo;

    //     // var urlFull = this.url + "TaLista?Tipo=Todos&Cod=" + Año + ":" + Mes;
    const u = `${URL}TaLista?Tipo=${tipoTA}&Cod=`;
    // const user = this.authService.user;
    if (tipoTA === "JefeZonal") {
      return `${u}${ano}:${mes}:${userCod}`;
    } else if (
      tipoTA === "Prevencion" ||
      tipoTA === "Comite" ||
      tipoTA === "Todos"
    ) {
      return `${u}${ano}:${mes}`;
    } else if (tipoTA === "Detalle") {
      return `${u}${ano}`;
    } else {
      return `${u}${userCod}:${ano}:${mes}`;
    }
  }

  updateMes(mes: number) {
    this.updateState({ ...this._state, mes, loading: true });
  }

  updateAno(ano: number) {
    this.updateState({ ...this._state, ano, loading: true });
  }

  updateUrl(url: string) {
    console.log(`updating url... new url is ${url}`);
    this.updateState({ ...this._state, url: this.urlEp[url], loading: true });
  }

  // --------------------- Private Methods ------------------------

  private updateState(state: TAState) {
    this._store.next(state);
  }

  /**
   * Obtener tarjetas amarillas segun ano y mes
   */
  getTarjetasAmarillas(url: string, ano: number, mes?: number) {
    const httpUrl = this.buildUrl(this.codUser, url, ano, mes);
    console.log(`url es: ${httpUrl}`);
    return this.http.get<DatoListaAmarilla[]>(httpUrl);
  }
}
```

This service keeps track of all observables and creates the `form` and sends it to the child component encharged with the search terms.

#### App structure

One root `app.module`, one `core.module` that is injected in the app module, on `shared.module` that is imported in different places as it is needed, 4 sibling lazy loaded modules, one of them is where I'm trying to implement this facade.

All this started after I saw [NgAir 205 - Pushed based facade](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HnNytR32Otk)

#### I have tried

1. Setting the `providedIn: 'root'` in this service
2. Injecting this service in the `providers` array in the root `@NgModule`.
3. Injecting it in the `providers` array in the core `@NgModule`

#### Where is located in the folder structure

This service lives in src/app/core/services it's exported in a barrel `index.ts` file

#### Some output when of the chrome's devtool console

This is as soon as I open the `TarjetaAmarillaModule`
[image]

And this is after I **clear the console** and choose a month and then a year.
[image]

You can see in the **second image** that the month is set to `6` but it changes to the month that was set in the declaration of `_state_` that was `new Date.getMonth() + 1`

Comment: Could you please provide a snippet using stackblitz.com ?

Comment: @edkeveked retweet

Comment: I'm trying to make it work there ASAP. I always have problems with stackblitz. Meanwhile, here it is [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/behavior-error-so?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcore%2Fservices%2Fta-facade.service.ts)

Comment: @KaiserCL - Looks like your stackblitz is not working. Could you rectify it.